# upload image without submit button in class componet in : react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to do a file upload to a api but i want it to happen with out a submit button
how can i upload a file to a api with out submit button

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
     
      files: {
        profile_img: null, 
      },
    };
```

on change funtion

```
onChange(e) {
    let files = this.state.files;
    files[e.target.name] = e.target.files[0];

    this.setState({
      files: files,
    });
  }
```

```
<input  type="file"name="profile_img" onChange={this.onChange}/>
```